# getting DB connection error message using shell scripts

Tags: database, shell, unix, plsql, scripting

I want to connect DB Using Unix shell script but I am getting error message 
Below have error message

> /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0.2/bin/sqlplus: symbol lookup error:
>   /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0.2/lib/libnnz10.so: undefined symbol:
>   nltrc_entry

```
ORACLE_HOME="/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0.2"; export ORACLE_HOME

ORACLE_SID="$schema"; export ORACLE_SID

value=`/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0.2/bin/sqlplus -S USER/USER99@$DB_HOSTNAME << EOF
SET LINESIZE 300
SET PAGESIZE 300
SET HEADING OFF
SELECT * FROM table;
EOF`
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with the LD path - if its not already set should probably be something like  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0.2/client/lib, otherwise you've got a mismatch between the packages installed on the server.